# Set Apache to Block HTTPS Requests to a Certain Subdomain

Tags: apache-2.4, https, http, apache2

I have these domains

```
domain.com
www.domain.com
srv.domain.com
```

pointing to the same server IP, but want my website to be accessible only via `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` which have SSL certificates. I run a TCP-based service accessed via `srv.domain.com`; there is no SSL certificate for it, but currently I can still access the website via this subdomain.

How should I configure Apache so that it blocks HTTPS (and HTTP) requests to this particular subdomain?

My configs look like this:

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

000-default-le-ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
    </IfModule>

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```